# Python: Using multiprocessing to partition a graph

Tags: python, graph, multiprocessing

I am modifying existing code in order to add multiprocessing. The code in question partitions a graph using a queue to generate columns for a multiple sequence alignment.

The serial code runs while the queue is not empty. The queue is initialized with a single graph.

```
graphs=[graph]
while graphs:
    g = graphs.pop()
    if g.is_column():
        #append data from graph to another list
        map_columns.append(g.lengths)
        continue
    l, r = g.split() 
    g.append(l)
    g.append(r)
```

I would like to make it so that the code has a pool of processes, which it fills up with graphs, then adds new graphs to the pool until there are no more graphs that aren't columns.

I've used the Python multiprocessing package before, but I'm not sure how to use it for this problem. How exactly would I go about sending a graph to a subprocess so that at most n processes are active (for n cores) and making sure that the loop ends once I really have no subgraphs left to partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every algorithm step you are generating a new set of graphs to work on. You can see it like a binary tree generator, so, you can have a pool of processes and run the algorithm for every tree level. At the begining (at the top of the tree) no parallelism will happen, but as you get down the tree generation, and if the tree is somewhat balanced, you will get benefits from this implementation.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue


pool = Pool(6)
result_queue = Queue()
graphs=[graph]
intermediary_graphs[graph]

def work(graphs):
    if g.is_column():
        #append data from graph to another list
        map_columns.append(g.lengths)
        return
    l, r = g.split() 
    intermediary_graphs.append(l)
    intermediary_graphs.append(r)
    result_queue.put(l, r)

while graphs:
    pool.map(work, graphs)
    graphs = []
    while not result_queue.empty():
        graphs.append(result_queue.get())
```

Please note I have not tested this. If this does not run, please use as a pseudo code and refine.

All intermediary graphs will be stored in `intermediary_graphs`, and the `graphs` variable will be emptied on every iteration and refilled with the new level of nodes from the tree of graphs we are generating.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've used the multiprocessing package successfully before, but for different problems. I'm not sure how to apply them to this particular algorithm, where I have one queue that starts with a single item.

Comment: @Wikt, good to know you already use the multiprocessing package. I have updated my answer with a proposal. I think it will run, but have not tested, there is only the algorithm idea. Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help - the code worked without issues!